# The Four Transitive Subgroups of $A_7$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory

I know that $A_7$ contains 3 transitive subgroups: $A_7, PSL(2,7), F_{21}$ (Alternating group of 7 elements, $PSL(2,7)$, Frobenius group of order 21).

In studying the Galois group structure of degree 7 polynomials, it seems that there is a 4th subgroup of $A_7$ that is transitive. I cannot seem to locate anything to indicate what this 4th group is.

Is there indeed a 4th transitive subgroup of $A_7$ distinct from the 3 I have listed above?

Comment: The regular group $C_7$ is also transitive and a subgroup of alternating.

Comment: Oh duh. Ummmmmm yeah. I guess it was much more obvious than I thought. Thanks.

Comment: @Derek, that's the first one in the author's list.

Comment: Sorry, sent that too late at night!

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question:

The four transitive subgroups of $A_7$ are as follows:

$$C_7, F_{21}, PSL(2,7), A_7$$